# Please explain following line in a proof

Tags: derivatives, proof-explanation

Given that

$p_c(s) = s^n + a_{n-1}s^{n-1}+......+ a_{1}s + k $

$p_m(s) = (p_c^{(m)}(s)/m!)$  for $m= 1,2....,n-1$

Thus

$p_c(s+\sigma) = s^n +p_{n-1}(\sigma)s^{n-1} +p_{n-2}(\sigma)s^{n-2}+.....+p_1(\sigma)s + p_c(\sigma)$

For $p_c(s+\sigma)$ to be stable , a necessary condition is that the polynomial coefficients  $p_i(\sigma)$ must be greater than $0$. This is achieved only when $\sigma > \lambda_{r max}$ 
where $\lambda_{r max} =$ maximum real root of all derivatives of $p_c(s)$

Please explain me the last line how  $\sigma > \lambda_{r max}$  ensures that necessary condition for stability is satisfied